# Array empty outside socket.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, socket.io

I understand that this has to do with asynchronous nature of javascript, but let me explain the problem since i've been scratching my head over it for a while now.

**Problem:** 
I have some data coming in from the server. On my client side, I have a `this.socket.on`, inside which I am getting the data from the server and trying to push it inside an array that I instantiated before the socket connection even began. I need the data to persist outside the socket connection.

**Here is the code... any help would be greatly appreciated:**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.table_data = [];

  // GET ALL EARTHQUAKES 
     this.socket = io('localhost:9000', {reconnection: true});

     this.socket.on('all_quakes_event', (data) => {      

     if (data) {                   
       data.features.forEach((el, idx) => {
        this.table_data.push(
      {
          key: el.id,
          mag: el.properties.mag,
          time: moment(el.properties.time).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'),
          time_readable: moment(el.properties.time).startOf('hour').fromNow(),
          title: el.properties.title
        },
        )        
    });    
   } // END IF
      console.log(this.table_data); // GOOD
     }); // END SOCKET EVENT  

     console.log(this.table_data); // EMPTY

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store `table_data` in the component state, and then use `setState` (or, in a functional component, the `useState` hook) to update it:

```
state = {
  table_data: []
}

componentDidMount() {

        // GET ALL EARTHQUAKES 
        this.socket = io('localhost:9000', {reconnection: true});

        this.socket.on('all_quakes_event', (data) => {          

            if (data) {

                const newData = data.features.map((el, idx) => {
                        return {
                            key: el.id,
                            mag: el.properties.mag,
                            time: moment(el.properties.time).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'),
                            time_readable: moment(el.properties.time).startOf('hour').fromNow(),
                            title: el.properties.title
                        }               
                });
                this.setState({ table_data: [...this.state.table_data, ...newData] }) // not sure exactly what you want to do with new data vs existing state, but this pattern should work regardless.     
            } // END IF
            console.log(this.table_data); // GOOD
        }); // END SOCKET EVENT  

        console.log(this.state.table_data); // will be empty until some data comes in from the socket.

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put socket functionality in a different function, and call that function from did mount. You'll have to disconnect during unmount or you'll have multiple socket connection for same client. Look for hoc pattern to expose the socket connection to multiple components ( which you'll need later).
Also did you initiate this.socket in constructor? I am pretty sure that'd go with await io.connect().

Answer (score 1):

2 things to be noted here:

1. Maintain a state and update it with new data. (@EthanLipkind has already covered it)
2. `componentDidMount` is executed only once. Your `console.log(this.state.table_data)` will always be empty. Do console.log in render method, you will see updated data when you receive new data from the server.

Additional note - De-register the listener in `componentWillUnmount` (if not done already)

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.close();
  }
```